# My question is about tenses

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> The doctor found that he **had been bitten** by a snake.

In this sentence **had been** is used, actually **had been** is used for progressive action for some time. But here **had been** is used.
Why shouldn't we use sentence as:

> "The doctor found that he **had bitten** by a snake"?

Answer (score 2):

> The doctor found that he had been bitten by a snake

This is a passive sentence in the simple past tense where the second part is in the past perfect describing what happened before he "found".

First the snake bit him, then he found out about it.

The past perfect continuous can also be used in the passive:

> The doctor found that he had been being bitten by a snake.

The difference is that with the continuous tense, the snake had been (in the past) bitting him for a period of time or continuously while in the perfect, it had bitten him is just a lapse action or fact.